# php symfony2 name of field's value

Tags: forms, orm, doctrine, tostring, symfony-2.3

I've got a problem with the name of displayed field's value. In my FormType i have something like below:

```
$builder->add(
            'level',
            'entity',
            array(
                'class' => 'AppBundle:Level',
                'label' => false,
                'property' => 'name',
                'mapped' => false,
                'attr' => array(
                    'class' => 'none'
                )
            )
        );
```

And insteed of property name, I would like to display my own result of toString() method. How can I do this?